# placing a textfield in a textarea

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm trying to place the variable name on button click in a textarea specifically after dear. Any help on how to do so?

```
clientname = Ext.create('Ext.form.TextField', {
        id : 'client_name',
        fieldLabel: 'Client Name',
        width :'20%'
    });


function onButtonClick(){       
    name=Ext.getCmp('client_name').getValue();
}

result = Ext.create('Ext.form.FormPanel', {
        width      : 400,
        bodyPadding: 0,
        id:'outcome',
        items: [{

            xtype     : 'textareafield',
            name      : 'message',
            anchor    : '100%',
            readOnly  : true,
            value     : 'Dear' 
        }]
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the value of your textarea and of your textfield and concatenate those values.

```
function onButtonClick(){     
    var textField = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('textfield[id=client_name]'),
        textArea = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('textareafield[name=message]');

    textArea.setValue(textArea.getValue() + textField.getValue());
}
```